# paw server on Beagleboard

Tags: android, webserver

I'm planning to use paw server on my Beagleboard(Android OS) unfortunately i'm facing difficulties in installing php plugin.

I don't find any plugins folder inside paw in my sdcard. 
please help me out....

Answer (score 2):

You have to first access the server through a browser.
Start the PAW Server.
Browse to your local ip:port, the address stated.
Then log in,
Then go to plugins, the link is on the left hand side.
Then, just download the ZIP archive and extract it into your PAW plugins folder (normally /sdcard/paw/html/app/plugins).
After extraction (and the reload of the main page), the plug-in should should be available in the "Plug-ins" menu.

check these resources out aswell

```
    http://fun2code-blog.blogspot.com/2011/04/paw-server-php.html
    http://code.google.com/p/phpliteadmin/wiki/AndroidModifyApplicationDatabases
    http://hex.ro/wp/blog/php-and-lighttpd-for-android/
```

Oh yeah, and after all of that, the answer to your question is simply create a directory named plugins under /sdcard/paw/html/app.